# How to pull the date in proper format from timestamp

Tags: oracle, timestamp

I am working in Oracle SQL Developer and have the following code

```
SELECT Trunc(assigned_date, 'IW') AS bonus_week 
FROM   (SELECT Trunc(blf.assigned_date) AS assigned_date 
        FROM   olap.bonus_lifecycle_fact blf)
```

I get output in this form

```
07-12-03

08-01-28

08-01-28

08-01-28

08-01-07
```

Which is DD-MM-YY

That's fine, except when  I export to Excel I get some wonky stuff happening.

```
eg: 08-01-28 becomes 08-01-2028.
```

I presume it is because  blf.assigned_date is a timestamp but I'm not sure to rectify it. Any and all help appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Probably Excel being "helpful", try exporting as csv.

Comment: Excel is the issue, not Oracle.  Format the Excel columns as a custom date format to match your criteria

Comment: I don't think its excel - if you enter 28 as year in excel its converting to 2028 similar to oracle's RR format. The year needs to be in 4 digits to be interpreted correctly to 1928 (assuming thats what the issue is here). OP can confirm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try formatting your date to use a full 4 digit year using the [to_char](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_char.php) function and then do an export to excel.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(Trunc(assigned_date, 'IW'), 'MM-DD-YYYY') AS bonus_week
```

**Note**: I am assuming you have an issue of 28 getting converted to 2028 instead of 1928. The solution above should fix that.

In addition, you can also change the formatting of excel column to show the year in 2 digits (28 instead of 1928 or 2028)

Comment: (if you're doing to_char on the date, you don't need the additional trunc in this case.)

Comment: SELECT TO_CHAR(Trunc(assigned_date, 'IW'), 'MM-DD-YYYY') AS bonus_week  
This worked! Thanks so much!